# Convert string into a variable to be used in a generic call

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, call, apiclient

I would like to create a generic call using api-client.

I want simplify my functions:

```
client.hello(params).then(
    (response) => {
         console.log(response)
    },
    (error) => {
         console.log(error)
    }
)
client.bye(params).then(
    (response) => {
         console.log(response)
    },
    (error) => {
         console.log(error)
    }
)
```

Using a unique function, something like:

```
generic=window['hello']

client.generic(params).then(
    (response) => {
         console.log(response)
    },
    (error) => {
         console.log(error)
    }
)
```

With window['hello'] do not work.

Comment: `let say = (what) => client[what].path(params).then(...); say('hello'); say('bye');`?

Comment: well, the `then` part seems to be completely duplicate code, you could extract those alreadyfor the rest, if it's alsways `client[name].path`, then also that can be parametrized